# Estimate Kubernetes resources for microservices

Tags: kubernetes

I want to run a test sever based on Kubernetes with around 60 Spring Boot microservices.

How I can estimate how much CPU, RAM and resources I will need.

Comment: Check the resource usage of your application. This totally depends on your application.

Comment: @Peter Penzov Pls try this: 
You can use utility command kubectl top ( node / pod) to get the resources metrics:
node Display resource (CPU/memory) usage of nodes 
pod Display resource (CPU/memory) usage of pods
Also, you can deploy Prometheus in order to get the full metrics from your cluster. and refer [doc1](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/) and [doc2](https://learnk8s.io/setting-cpu-memory-limits-requests).

Answer (score 0):

You can start by first running your application under a realistic load for it and use any instrumentation tools to measure how much CPU/memory an instance of your micro-service consumes. Note this value for CPU and memory.

A simple calculation might suggest `total = 60* size_of_instance` but you have to be mindful of the overhead in your infrastructure as well.

If your k8s environment has certain 'infrastructure components' running on your worker nodes, you need to be able to add those in your equation as well. So, the final requirement of your node will be (assuming you want to run them all on a single node):
`Total = 60 * size_of_instance + infra_overhead_on_node`

Comment: Is it possible to run Kubernetes on a VPS? For example VPS with a 6 GB of RAM or it's recommended to use bare-metal server?

Comment: it is possible for k8s to run on a virtual box, but the recommendation is for it to be on bare metal box

Comment: Well at least for development purposes it will be useful.

Comment: Yes you totally can! It's called `minikube` and you can find more details [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/). You can run this locally and play with it to test your functional requirements of the infrastructure, before you commit to something more expensive like a public cloud instance :)

Comment: Is it possible to run Kubernetes in a Server with only 2 CPU cores?

Comment: When you say `server` do you mean an instance in a public cloud? or a local virtual machine? Because the answer will differ.

I will assume you mean your local machine's VM where you have 2 CPU cores to spare. I think it should be totally possible to do that. At least from a functional perspective where you have enough of a setup to be able to do certain things.

Comment: I'm referring to both cases.

Comment: In case of a public cloud instance, many services can be managed, for instance your control plane can be managed. This means you will not require the resource overhead of the k8s core elements (api-server, core-dns, controller-manager, etcd etc.) on your node and it will be a worker node in true sense.

For a single-node type setup locally, you'll most probably be running control plane components on the same node, which will reduce the available resources for your testing. That's all. 

I still think it should be possible though.

Answer (score 0):

There is no exact estimate.
You can spin up all your instances, assuming they all 60 run different code, stress-test them, and monitor the CPU + Mem, then double that just so they have room to breathe.. which might also prove to not be enough, depending on your code for each pod..

So, test, adjust, test again, adjust again (with some buffer in mind, so pods do not die due to resource exhaustion), repeat, repeat again, and again :)

If you can, optimize the pods so they use less resources, better code, etc...

Comment: Is it possible to run Kubernetes in a Server with only 2 CPU cores?

Comment: Yes. https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/